# Camera strap attachment - Why no spring clips?

Tags: camera-straps

I've been searching for a new camera strap as I've grown my collection (oops).

I now have a selection of different formats and sizes of camera:

- Canon 6D mkII (main shooter)
- Lubitel 166B (120 medium format TLR)
- Canon Sure Shot Zoom XL (35mm compact)
- Bronica ETRSI (120 medium format SLR)
- Fuji Instax

I am hoping to find a strap that I can use interchangeably with all of these cameras and in my searching I have found that most detachable solutions appear to have a detachable module system like the Peak Design options, where the loopy bit goes on the camera and the disc slides into the strap holder:

[image]

My question is... Why aren't there many (or any) main manufacturers producing straps with spring clips instead? For reference, when I say "spring clip" I mean something like this (for reference, the image here is a pet leash...):

[image]

It seems that something like this - Could also be a smaller clip for use-ability - should work just as well as the Peak Design? It may even be better aesthetically as you wouldn't have the little toggles still connected to the camera when you detach it, if you were to display the camera for example?

Are there any downsides to a strap connector like this?
Are there any manufacturers producing straps like this?

Comment: One reason is in your picture. Compare the attachments with the attachments on your Canon camera (made for something wide an flat like a lanyard). You would need several shapes of hooks, while the string goes everywhere.

Comment: @xenoid most have those triangular keyrings on to accommodate too. I'd be happy to do that for the ease of taking my strap on and off. Much prefer a small triangle then a floppy string with a circle on the end.

Comment: Personally I went for a strap (BlackRapid) that uses the screw thread at the bottom. A big advantage is that I can put the strap either on the camera or on the tripod collar of the lens (I often lug a 120-400 lens).

Comment: @xenoid The big disadvantage of those is that all it usually takes is a 1mm thick or so piece of metal on the top of the swivel to break and you'll drop everything onto the floor/concrete/pavement/ground. It also ties up your tripod thread so that you can't leave QR plates such as Swiss/Arca style plates or L-brackets attached.

Comment: Triangular keyring style connectors are for cameras with studs that have a small hole drilled trough them, such as classic Nikons. Canon uses metal lugs that are 3/8" wide.

Comment: @MichaelC My cheap knock-off did break early (2.5kg camera+lens) but was repaired/improved with a sail carabiner. When padding wore out I replaced it with a brand one that hasn't broken yet. And there is at least one model that comes with a special quick-release plate that has a loop.

Comment: @xenoid Meh. I prefer redundancy. I use an Op/Tech system that attaches at two points (usually the right top lug and the lug on the right side of the bottom of the grip that is several inches away from the tripod socket) on the camera and are each independently attached to the sling strap. I've never had a piece of the hardware to fail, but I have had a couple of times when I didn't click one of the QD connectors all the way in. The other, redundant connection prevented anything from hitting the ground.

Answer (score 2):

The main downside to metal clips or rings are that they scratch the camera around the connection point. This used to be no big deal for most folks. For those that it was, there were little leather pads attached to the ends of some straps to protect the camera from the metal hardware.

[image]

Some such straps came with metal clips rather than 3/8" loop ends.

[image]

In the present era, it seems that everyone is obsessed with their electronic devices being cosmetically flawless. Most people put protective covers on our phone screens, camera screens, phone backs and sides, etc. So metal hardware at the end of straps that would come into contact with the camera have fallen out of vogue.

But there are still more than a few "boutique" strap makers that offer such straps. Just do a google search for "vintage camera strap" (also select "Images" to easier see what the different results look like) and many of them will have metal clip ends on them.

Then there is Op/Tech, who has a near endless number of connector styles that are modular so they work with all of their strap, sling, and harness styles. The ends tend to be very affordable as well, usually around $8/set for most types. So you can buy the strap you want, then mix/match various ends until you find what works for you without breaking the bank.

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me that some people consider a shiny new-looking camera to be a _good_ thing.  They would be horrified by some of mine!

Answer (score 1):

[OP/TECH USA](https://www.optechusa.com) produce many different straps and connectors, which can be combined together to produce many different strap variations. I was recently considering something similar to what you're asking about... I thought of using their [Adapt-Its](https://www.optechusa.com/adapt-its.html) together with their [Swivel Hook Connectors](https://www.optechusa.com/swivel-hook.html), and combine that with an [Envy Strap](https://www.optechusa.com/envy-strap.html) I already have. I wanted the strap connectors on the camera to be as "low profile" as possible, to make it easier to get in and out of a tight camera bag.

What put me personally off though is the fear that the swivel hooks could easily mar/scratch the camera body – a camera I'm unsure I'll keep over the longer term, and so I want to keep it in good condition, to maximise resale potential.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the main concern would be that the metal of the clasp would mar the surface of the camera and reduce its value. And I guess plastic swivel clips wouldn't be secure/strong enough? Although it does seem that many straps utilise plastic slide releases... so I guess plastic _should_ be ok...

Comment: Plastic clips can also cause fine scratches, particularly on the clear covers for LCD displays. On my Canon bodies which have top monochrome LCD settings screens, the plastic clips from the Op/Tech quick disconnects have left their mark. I've never sold a body, though. If I'm done with them they're usually worth so little I just donate them to the local high school's photography department.